# value returned by the fork() system call

Tags: process, fork

Why doesn't the fork() system call return the process ID of the parent to the child and return zero to parent?

```
pid_t pid;
pid = fork();
```

In this section, the return code for the fork() is zero for the child and the (non zero) process id of the child is the returned to the parent.

How can i find out the PID of the parent from the child?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46368813/fork-returns-0-but-the-child-process-getpid-0-why it is all very well explained over here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save it before doing the fork().  fork() is written to return the id that wouldn't be known until the fork had been done.

Answer (score 0):

You can always get the PID of the parent before the fork and keep it in a variable. It will be the same after the fork.
Just run:

```
pid_t parent;
....
parent = getpid();
pid = fork(); //If pid is 0 your parent's pid is in parent
```